IBIS File pin Matching
STM32MP153CAA3
I will make pin mapping for ibis LPDDR2 CK enable pin for STM32MP153CAA3. Which one should I choose among the model selector options?
Which characteristic impedance should I choose for this LPDDR2 CKE pin? How do we determine this? Can this be selected in the RAM initialization sequence?



